# How to make a JavaScript 'getElementById' work on an HTML CSS Toggle Switch

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to activate my HTML/ CSS 'Toggle Switch' using JavaScript.

I'd like the DIV with text to be hidden by default, and when the slider (switcher) is swiped to the left then it 'triggers' the DIV to be 'shown' using JavaScript.

I how that I am on the right path but there's just something not quite right with my action...

```js
function toggleDiv() {
  var triggeredDiv = document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv');
  if (document.getElementById('flipswitch').checked) {
    triggeredDiv.classList.remove('shown');
  } else {
    triggeredDiv.classList.add('shown');
  }
}

document.getElementById('flipswitch').addEventListener("change", toggleDiv);
```

```css
.flipswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.flipswitch input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.flipswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.flipswitch-inner {
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -ms-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.flipswitch-inner:before,
.flipswitch-inner:after {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flipswitch-inner:before {
  content: "MONTHLY";
  padding-left: 12px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #888888;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.flipswitch-inner:after {
  content: "BY COUNTRY";
  padding-right: 12px;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  color: #888888;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.flipswitch-switch {
  width: 45px;
  margin: 7.5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 139px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.flipswitch-cb:checked+.flipswitch-label .flipswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.flipswitch-cb:checked+.flipswitch-label .flipswitch-switch {
  right: 0;
}

.triggeredDiv {
  display: none;
}

.triggeredDiv.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flipswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="flipswitch" class="flipswitch-cb" id="fs" checked>
  <label class="flipswitch-label" for="fs">
    <div class="flipswitch-inner"></div>
    <div class="flipswitch-switch"></div>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="triggeredDiv">
  Show Text
</div>
```

Comment: The id of flip switch is "fs", not "flipswitch"

Comment: FYI, your `if` statement can be eliminated by using `toggle` with a switch argument. `triggeredDiv.classList.toggle('shown', !document.getElementById('flipswitch').checked);` When the switch arg is `true`, the class will be added, otherwise will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `document.getElementById` you should be using something to get the elements by `class`, since that is what's defined in your markup.

Additionally, your input checkbox isn't toggling `checked`, it's simply toggling the state of the `triggered` div.

We can make this work by adjusting the code:

```
function toggleDiv() {
   this.element || ( this.element = document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv') );

   this.element.classList.toggle("shown");
  }
```

---

*With comments for better understanding:*

```
function toggleDiv() {
  /*
   if we don't have a reference in `toggleDiv.element` 
   we use `document.querySelector` to retrieve
   and save the reference to the element `.triggeredDiv`
   this ensures that we only go through the DOM once to retrieve the element
   no matter how many times the function is called
   which is more performant. 
  */
  this.element || (this.element = document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv'));

  /*
   after we have the element, we simply toggle the `shown` class
   using the `classList.toggle` method.
  */
   this.element.classList.toggle("shown");
}

  document.querySelector('.flipswitch').addEventListener("change", toggleDiv);
```

```js
function toggleDiv() {
   this.element || ( this.element = document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv') );
   
   this.element.classList.toggle("shown");
  }
  
  document.querySelector('.flipswitch').addEventListener("change", toggleDiv);
```

```css
.flipswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.flipswitch input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.flipswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.flipswitch-inner {
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -ms-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.flipswitch-inner:before,
.flipswitch-inner:after {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flipswitch-inner:before {
  content: "MONTHLY";
  padding-left: 12px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #888888;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.flipswitch-inner:after {
  content: "BY COUNTRY";
  padding-right: 12px;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  color: #888888;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.flipswitch-switch {
  width: 45px;
  margin: 7.5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 139px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.flipswitch-cb:checked+.flipswitch-label .flipswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.flipswitch-cb:checked+.flipswitch-label .flipswitch-switch {
  right: 0;
}

.triggeredDiv {
  display: none;
}

.triggeredDiv.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flipswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="flipswitch" class="flipswitch-cb" id="fs" checked>
  <label class="flipswitch-label" for="fs">
    <div class="flipswitch-inner"></div>
    <div class="flipswitch-switch"></div>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="triggeredDiv">
  Show Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are trying to reference the flipswitch by an id of flipswitch while you gave the switch an id of fs. The references in the javascript just have to be changed to be:

```
document.getElementById('fs')
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('flipswitch')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you just change the two instances of `document.getElementById('flipswitch')` to `document.getElementById('fs')` in your function your code works fine.

JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/oq8wL2v4/